# Turn On GPS on Android 5.O.2 Lollipop not work Sony Experia Z1, other device work properly

Tags: android, gps

on MapActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //show error dialog if GooglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_map);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
    progressDialog.show();

    turnGPSOn();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //   TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("Start Point")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
    );


    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15.5f), 4000, null);

    progressDialog.dismiss();
    latAwal = location.getLatitude();
    lngAwal = location.getLongitude();
}

private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}


public void setUpMapIfNeeded(){
    if (googleMap == null){

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        notifLokasi();

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

    } if (googleMap != null){
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

public  void notifLokasi(){
    LatLng BLENDUK = new LatLng(-6.968213698041749,110.42742323130369);
    Marker blenduk = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(BLENDUK)
            .title("Sejarah-Gereja Blenduk")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj1))
            .snippet("Gereja Blenduk,Semarang Kota Lama"));

    LatLng jiwasraya = new LatLng(-6.9686366862013776,110.42737729847431);
    Marker JiwasRaya = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(jiwasraya)
            .title("Sejarah-Gedung Jiwasraya")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj2))
            .snippet("Gedung Jiwasraya,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Mberok = new LatLng(-6.968722215625485,110.42517822235823);
    Marker mberok = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mberok)
            .title("Sejarah-Jembatan Mberok")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj3))
            .snippet("Jembatan Mberok,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng GMandiri = new LatLng(-6.968400731405668,110.42524963617325);
    Marker gmandiri = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(GMandiri)
            .title("Sejarah-Gedung Mandiri")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj4))
            .snippet("Gedung Mandiri,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Lyod = new LatLng(-6.968154126901272,110.42524795979261);
    Marker lyod = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Lyod)
            .title("Sejarah-Djakarta Lyod")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj5))
            .snippet("Djakarta Lyod,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Tawang = new LatLng(-6.964333238108265,110.42773302644491);
    Marker tawang = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Tawang)
            .title("Sejarah-Stasiun Tawang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj6))
            .snippet("Stasiun Tawang,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Prau = new LatLng(-6.966292108945976,110.4271499812603);
    Marker prau = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Prau)
            .title("Sejarah-Pabrik Rokok Praoe Lajar")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj7))
            .snippet("Pabrik Rokok Prau Lajar,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng MrBunta = new LatLng(-6.965792574363458,110.42972389608622);
    Marker mrbunta = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(MrBunta)
            .title("Sejarah-Gedung Marabunta")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj8))
            .snippet("Gedung Marabunta,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Marba = new LatLng(-6.968545499171693,110.42803511023521);
    Marker marba = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Marba)
            .title("Sejarah-Gedung Marba")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mksj9))
            .snippet("Gedung Marba,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Angkringa = new LatLng(-6.968192731663565,110.42823124676943);
    Marker angkringan = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Angkringa)
            .title("Sejarah-Angkringa Blenduk")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkul1))
            .snippet("Angkringan Blenduk,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Sate = new LatLng(-6.968576782315264,110.42772129178047);
    Marker sate = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Sate)
            .title("Kuliner-Sate Kambing 29")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkkl2))
            .snippet("Sate Kambing 29,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng IBC = new LatLng(-6.9686985868756475,110.42686466127634);
    Marker ibc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(IBC)
            .title("Kuliner-Ikan Bakar Cianjur")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkkl3))
            .snippet("Ikan Bakar Cianjur,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Cafe = new LatLng(-6.967544437475304,110.4279100522399);
    Marker cafe = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Cafe)
            .title("Kuliner-Retro Cafe")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkkl4))
            .snippet("Retro Cafe,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng SCAG = new LatLng(-6.967490523852544,110.42818564921618);
    Marker scag = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(SCAG)
            .title("Rekreasi-Semarang Contenporer Art Gallery")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkrk1))
            .snippet("Semarang Contenporer Art Gallery,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng Srigunting = new LatLng(-6.968171099685091,110.42781382799149);
    Marker srigunting = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Srigunting)
            .title("Rekreasi-Taman Srigunting")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkrk2))
            .snippet("Taman Srigunting,Kota Lama,Semarang"));

    LatLng PTawang = new LatLng(-6.9653346394619021,110.42811222374439);
    Marker ptawang = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Srigunting)
            .title("Rekreasi-Polder Tawang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mkrk2))
            .snippet("Polder Tawang,Kota Lama,Semarang"));
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    googleMap.clear();
    latAwal = latLng.latitude;
    lngAwal = latLng.longitude;
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latAwal,lngAwal))
                    .title("Start Perjalanan")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
    );

    notifLokasi();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.fab)
public void onFabClick() {
    data = getIntent().getExtras();
    Tujuan = data.getString("Tujuan");
    if (Tujuan.equals("Gereja Blenduk")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968213698041749;
        lngTujuan = 110.42742323130369;
    } else if (Tujuan.equals("Gedung Jiwasraya")) {
        latTujuan = -6.9686366862013776;
        lngTujuan = 110.42737729847431;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Jembatan Mberok")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968722215625485;
        lngTujuan = 110.42517822235823;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Gedung Mandiri")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968400731405668;
        lngTujuan = 110.42524963617325;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Djakarta Lyod")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968154126901272;
        lngTujuan = 110.42524795979261;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Stasiun Tawang")) {
        latTujuan = -6.964333238108265;
        lngTujuan = 110.42773302644491;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Pabrik Rokok Praoe Lajar")) {
        latTujuan = -6.966292108945976;
        lngTujuan = 110.4271499812603;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Gedung Marabunta")) {
        latTujuan = -6.965792574363458;
        lngTujuan = 110.42972389608622;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Gedung Marba")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968545499171693;
        lngTujuan = 110.42803511023521;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Angkringan Blenduk")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968192731663565;
        lngTujuan = 110.42823124676943;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Sate Kambing 29")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968576782315264;
        lngTujuan = 110.42772129178047;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Ikan Bakar Cianjur")) {
        latTujuan =-6.9686985868756475;
        lngTujuan = 110.42686466127634;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Retro Cafe")) {
        latTujuan = -6.967544437475304;
        lngTujuan = 110.4279100522399;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("SEMARANG ART GALLERY")) {
        latTujuan = -6.967490523852544;
        lngTujuan = 110.42818564921618;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("Taman Srigunting")) {
        latTujuan = -6.968171099685091;
        lngTujuan = 110.42781382799149;
    }  else if (Tujuan.equals("PPOLDER TAWANG")) {
        latTujuan = -6.9653346394619021;
        lngTujuan = 110.42811222374439;
    }

    GoHasilRute();
}

public  void GoHasilRute(){
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putDouble("latAwal", latAwal);
    data.putDouble("lngAwal", lngAwal);
    data.putDouble("latTujuan", latTujuan);
    data.putDouble("lngTujuan", lngTujuan);
    data.putString("Tujuan", Tujuan);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewRouteActivity.class).putExtras(data));
}
}
```

I want to get Current location,with GPS is On,
but in Android 5.0.2 , Device Sony Z1 , GPS cannot automaticly On ,
in other device Himax 4.4,Huawei , ZenFone , this is work.

Updated:
Parshant , I Call function OnCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_map);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

 //   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 //   progressDialog.setMessage("Mendapatkan Lokasi Saya.. Tunggu");
 //   progressDialog.show();

    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(AddMapActivity.this);
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
    }
    else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the hack that your `turnGPSOn()` method uses was remedied several Android versions ago. I'm surprised if you got it working at all on any newer device. Anyway, GPS can (should) only be enabled/disabled by the user directly. That is, your app can't do it by itself, on newer Android versions, at least.

Comment: sorry , i try it on older version Mike..

Comment: any advice to getCurrenlocation on Android 5.0 +

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

// Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog
        .setMessage("Please allow access of location to get current location. To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app.");

// On pressing Settings button
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

// on pressing cancel button
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();
```

}

Comment: Parshant , i've update my question , i Call GPSTracker , inside OnCreate , after i run my app , this is not showing alert , ... is the problem with gruddle ? or anything else?

Comment: What is your problem now i am not able to getting. This code check is your gps is off or on.

Comment: Tq So Much Parshant.., I'll try to find the Problem...,